# Variables Being Reset

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below class takes a list and then using the move_pieces method, switches the order of the last two items and returns a new list.  Somehow, when I run the below code, the method isn't returning a new list, but saving over the self.state and the 'test' list I've created to run the code.  Any thoughts?

```
class node:

    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def move_piece(self):
        new_node = self.state
        new_node[7] , new_node[8] = new_node[8] , new_node[7]
        return new_node

test = [1,3,4,8,6,2,7,0,5]
test_node = node(test)
test_node.move_piece()
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code.... can you boil it down to a simple example? But if you don't want to change the original list, just copy the list and change the copy.

Comment: Indeed a lot of code and I am not quite sure what the method should do and what the expected output is. From a first sight, I would think `zero_idx` and `item_idx` are switched ( line 82, 83)?

Comment: Sorry guys.  New to the stackoverflow.  The move_piece method should take self.state (which is a list) and return another list (self.state reordered).  But when I use the method, the value of self.state is being changed instead of just returning a new list and keeping self.state the same.

Comment: @priorfire4411 Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for improving the quality of your question. Your issue is a lot clearer and I have upvoted it to reflect that.

> ...instead of making a copy of the instances state and returning that with the last two items switched, the program switches the items and saves over the self.state attribute. Any thoughts?

That's because of the line `new_node = self.state`, which essentially declares a second reference to the same array in memory as `self.state`. Any changes made using `new_node` will change the array pointed to by `self.state` as well.

To change this, you can create a copy of the list by replacing `new_node = self.state` with `new_node = self.state[:]`:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def move_piece(self):
        new_node = self.state[:]
        new_node[7] , new_node[8] = new_node[8] , new_node[7]
        return new_node

test = [1,3,4,8,6,2,7,0,5]
test_node = node(test)
test_out = test_node.move_piece()
print('test:\t\t\t\t{}'.format(test))
print('test_node.state:\t{}'.format(test_node.state))
print('test_out:\t\t\t{}'.format(test_out))
```

**Output**

```
test:               [1, 3, 4, 8, 6, 2, 7, 0, 5]
test_node.state:    [1, 3, 4, 8, 6, 2, 7, 0, 5]
test_out:           [1, 3, 4, 8, 6, 2, 7, 5, 0]
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  I will be sure to spend time being more concise in the future.  Thanks again!

Comment: @priorfire4411 No worries, but on Stack Overflow [voting on and accepting answers that solve your problem are preferred over 'thank you' comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).